# ADB2C UserPrincipleName different depending on how user created

Tags: azure, authentication, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am facing basically the same issue as the user in [this post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/240295/azure-directory-userprincipalname-is-different.html).

If I create a user in ADB2C using the graph API, even though I set an ObjectIdentity of "emailAddress" on the request, the email is not set as the user principle name.

After much frustration, we found that although the user principle name shows the correct email in the portal, the upn returned over the graph api and required for login is actually {objectid}@{issuerdomain}.

The linked post above suggests this is expected, **however** if we create the user *directly in the Azure portal* then the UPN is their actual email address, so it definitely is possible.

Am I missing something? The fact that the UPN is, apparently deliberately, shown incorrectly in the portal for graph-created users is so stupid, it lost us hours of time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - problem solved. It turned out the email address (parsed from csv) had a leading space.

This was basically impossible to spot in the portal and must have caused AD to fall back to a default email as the provided one was invalid.

I **really** wish AD had rejected it instead of silently accepting it, displaying it and replacing with a default username in the background.

Also that response from MS that I linked to in the question saying it can't be done was clearly incorrect.

Comment: For B2C user accounts: The Graph API returns UPN. This UPN will always be @contoso.onmicrosoft.com, as UPNs must reside on a verified domain name. The Azure Portal shows UPN, it will retrieved from the `identities` collection returned by Graph API. Azure Portal doesn't return that actual UPN for B2C users. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes#identities-attribute